# Mako Template lookup error: TypeError

Tags: python, mako

I have a big massive mako file which I am currently breaking down to smaller files for the ease of maintenance. 
Consider main.mako as my primary(massive) template file 
and get_raps.mako as my small file that needs to be included.

main.mako

```
<%include file="/get_raps.mako"/>
```

get_raps.mako

```
% for rap in rapset.raps:
  <% print rap %>
%endfor
```

And in my code:

```
dirlookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[
        os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__),
            'templates'
        )])

template = Template(
            filename=os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(__file__),
                'templates',
                'LegacyXML.mako'
            ),
            output_encoding="utf-8",
        lookup=dirlookup
    )
```

When I run this I get an error :

```
 {'coset': <models.Coset.Coset object at 0x109daf990>, 'rap': <models.Raps.Rap.Rap object at 0x109dafa50>}
    {'coset': <models.Coset.Coset object at 0x109dafd50>, 'rap': <models.Raps.Rap.Rap object at 0x109daf550>}
    {'coset': models.Coset.Coset object at 0x109dafd90>, 'rap': <models.Raps.Rap.Rap object at 0x109dafe10>}

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 899, in _exec_template
        callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
      File "_get_raps_mako", line 30, in render_body
    TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable
```

I know I am reaching the small file with data but why I get the type error? 
Am I missing something that is very obvious? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this statement that you need to change:

`<%include file="/get_raps.mako"/>`

Because the `include` statement needs the correct path of the file. Are you certain that you keep the file in your root? (Why?)